# Reference request: Markoff type equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Consider the equation $x^2+ay^2+bz^2=(1+a+b)xyz.$ If there are infinitely many integral solutions, then up to permutations $(a,b)=(1,1),(1,2),(2,3).$ I have found a presentation by Waldschmidt (https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/MarkoffEn.pdf). I would like to ask about a standard reference related to this result.

Comment: Mordell's book on Diophantine equations has a lot about Markoff equations (but I don't know whether it answers your specific question).

Comment: What do you mean by "if $(1, 1,1)$ is a solution"? How can in be not a solution?

Comment: You are right of course, (1,1,1) is a solution anyway, modified accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I understand. Given integers $1 \leq a \leq b,$ we can travel out of the $(1,1,1)$ solution of
$$ x^2 + a y^2 + b z^2 = (1+a+b) \; xyz    $$
 with "jumps"
$$ x' = (1+a+b) \; yz - x \; , \;  $$ 
$$ y' = \left(\frac{1+a+b}{a} \right) \; zx - y \; , \;  $$
$$ z' = \left(\frac{1+a+b}{b} \right) \; xy - z \; . \;  $$
In order for this to always work, we need integer coefficients, or both
$$  a | (b+1) \; , \; $$
$$  b | (a+1) \; . \; $$
If $b > 1,$ we need $b = a+1,$ hence $a | (a+2)$ and $a | 2.$ That is,
$$  a \leq 2 \; , \; \;  b = a+1 \; \; .  $$

References include [KAP and me](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Illinois_2003.pdf) and [HURWITZ](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf). I imagine Waldschmidt knows some more references related to the $(1,a,b)$ examples. I think I will do a few layers of the 1,2,3 tree, this is new to me.
$$ x^2 + 2 y^2 + 3 z^2 = 6  xyz    $$
  The three jumps are 
$$ x' = 6yz - x \; , \; \;  y' = 3 zx - y \; , \; \; z' = 2xy - z \; \; . $$

[image]